# (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Unexpected Error. Deployed Version

Tags: google-app-engine, docker

I am trying to push an update to my managed vm using the command:

```
gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default --version "tacos"
```

This has been working great and all of a sudden it throws:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Unexpected Error. Deployed Version: tacos.384484674339405112
```

Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: run with `gcloud --verbosity debug preview app deploy app.yaml` with the rest of your options. This should allow you to have more insight into your issue

Comment: It looks like this has something to do with port forwarding, when I remove the lines:

    network:
       forwarded_ports: ["80"]

out of the config it works, I have reported it to Google and they are getting back to me. I am trying to get websockets for Nodejs on managed vms to work.